# Can you use a student ID to check in at a hotel?

Tags: paperwork, hotels, check-in

Out of curiosity, can you use your college ID as a form of identification when you're checking into a hotel? Or are there certain specifications for IDs that can be used for that?

Comment: This is most likely going to come down to specific hotel policy

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about the hotels you have in mind. I've stayed in big international hotels that have insisted on passport and credit card, and small places that have just been happy that I'm paying them.

Comment: It depends on the country. You can often get away with school IDs in the US, but in China by law you need to have a government photo ID. While in Japan, school IDs are universally accepted as equivalent to driver's licenses and passports.

Comment: It also depends on the place and the hotel you're in. In California no one said anything, but in Massachusetts I usually had to have a government issued ID.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the hotel. Many require an official **government-issued** form of identification.  So while a lax/kind hotel clerk may let you off with just the student ID, it's highly likely that they could reject it, and you'd probably have no legal recourse, lose your money (if in their terms) and be without a bed for the night :/

For an example, here's a [random one from a quick google](http://www.nanuhotels.in/Services-HotelPolicies):

> According to government regulations, a valid Photo ID has to be
>   carried by every person above the age of 18 staying at the hotel. The
>   identification proofs accepted are Drivers License, Voters Card,
>   Passport, Ration Card. Without valid ID the guest will not be allowed
>   to check in. Note- PAN Cards will not be accepted as a valid ID card.

Again, it'll depend on the hotel, and sometimes the laws of the country.

Comment: Do you have any sort of reference for this? I've stayed at small hotels and guest houses that have been happy to accept whatever address I give them along with payment for my stay.

Comment: @CannonFodder address? I thought this was about ID.  Regardless, I've updated my answer with an example terms and conditions from a hotel that requires it.

Comment: By "address" read "details". They've not asked for any formal ID, just a credible name and address, which I don't believe they've ever bothered to check. I think the presence of hard currency or other payment t up front has been sufficient. This has only been smaller places in provincial towns, but the OP wasn't specific.

Comment: @CannonFodder fair enough. Suspect it'll come down to the hotel or the law in the end, but it'd be worth contacting the hotel to make sure rather than risking it.